# How to choose the right keymap?

Tags: linux, keymap

I have several Dell XPS13 laptops running Gentoo Linux.  The latest one (which I bought used) has an Indian Rupee symbol beside the "4" on the 4 key and a Euro symbol beside the "5" on the 5 key.  None of the F1/F2/F3/etc keys are working correctly so I think I need to change the keymap.  How can I figure out which keymap to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a BIOS setting for changing the Function key behavior and switching it completely fixed this.

Comment: @stackoverflowrocks - Which setting exactly?

Comment: @meatspace, not for 2 days.

Comment: @Ramhound, it was called "Function Key Setting" or something like that.  I would have to reboot to find out for sure.